# how to handle large categorical values in data frame?

Tags: machine-learning, categorical-data, many-categories

I have over 2 million records which I am using to build the machine learning model. But I have a column with categorical values over 1600. I cannot convert the data into 1600 1-dimensional columns `(1,0,0,...)` which makes my data frame too complex with a large number of dimensions. Is there any way I can handle the categorical data more efficiently?

Reference to some research papers will also help

Comment: What is the data?

Comment: Why you can't ?

Comment: @Jon values such as 'ABC123' describes some service related to it. I have 1600 different values like that in a column.

Comment: @Tim I can convert into 1600 columns won't that become too complex to handle along with other 300+ columns

Comment: You need to tell us more... What exactly is your data? What do you want to do with it? What are your limitations (e.g. RAM, disc space)? In this form the question is unanswerable, because e.g. if you're Google, then there is no problem. On another hand, if you want to run a complicated model on your 5-year-old PC, then there is no point in even thinking of it because your data is possibly already too big.

Comment: It's a binary classification problem implementing in production level. over all I have 26 million records. My question is that is there any alternate way apart from splitting the columns into 1600 columns?

Comment: @vinaykaragod, there shouldn't be a difference between 10 columns vs 100000 columns as long as you have more samples than columns. This should just be a memory issue.

Comment: It's scarcely even a RAM issue if you use sparse matrices for the calculations.

Answer (score 3):

you can use label encoding for that categorical feature or try to find a way to group those 1600 categorical values to reduce the number of categories and then you can use one hot encoding. http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html this might help.